# Null value lingers in cache after Cache.Remove(key)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, caching

I added a caching layer between my ASP.NET MVC application and database using the `GetOrStore<T>` cache helper below.

This includes caching users' system roles.

When I remove a cached roles object for a signed-in user via `HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove(userRoleCacheKey)`, subsequent requests fail with a NullReferenceException because the cache helper is returning a null value for the role cache, even though the cached key should not exist and the helper should regenerate it.

It seems like the cached key lingers around with a `null` value. The exception won't budge until I request a role-heavy page a few seconds later.

Why is my cache breaking?

```
public static class CacheExtensions
{
    public static T GetOrStore<T>(this Cache cache, string key, Func<T> generator)
    {
        var result = cache.Get(key);

        if (result == null)
        {
            result = generator();
            if (result != null) // can't store null values in cache.
            {
                cache[key] = result;
            }
        }
        return (T)result;
    }
}
```

Here is the code that fetches the user's roles and caches it:

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string userId)
{
    return HttpRuntime.Cache.GetOrStore<string[]>(
        "RolesForUser[" + userId + "]",
        () => Con.Query<string>("SELECT Role FROM vw_UserRoles WHERE UserId = @userId", new { userId = Guid.Parse(userId)  }).ToArray());
}
```

where `Con` retrieves an open `IDbConnection`.

Comment: Do you have any objects in cache whose classes override equality (and `==` operator)?

Comment: Good question. None that I know of, but this role object is a `string[]`.

Comment: Added code that utilises the cache helper in my custom role provider.

Comment: In case of `string[]` objects maybe NullReferenceException is not caused by the object's null value, but the empty array? E.g. you call First() method on it and get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Minor issue in your code that can hide the problem from you:

```
if (result != null) // can't store null values in cache.
{
    cache[key] = result;
}
```

What about `else` clause? The result returned anyway, even if it is null value. Throw `InvalidOperationException` in that case and debug your queries passed as `generator` parameter.